# Get information about a private GitHub App while authenticated as another GitHub App

Tags: github, github-api, github-app

I'm trying to get information about a private GitHub App (`app-1`), while authenticated as another GitHub App (`app-2`). They are both private apps within my organization.

[This](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/apps/apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-an-app) is the endpoint I'm using. It says "Works with GitHub Apps", so I'm assuming it should work?

I've generated an access token for `app-2` using a private key and the app id, as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-json-web-token-jwt-for-a-github-app).

Then I generated an App Installation Token using curl:

```
curl --request POST \
--url "https://api.github.com/app/installations/INSTALLATION_ID/access_tokens" \
--header "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer JWT" \
--header "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
```

Then I'm using the resulting token from that call to make another call:

```
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/apps/app-1
```

I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` response with the following body:

```
{
    "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/apps/apps#get-an-app"
}
```

Isn't this supposed to work? If I change the slug name to the authenticated app (`app-2`) then the request succeeds.

Comment: The token is scoped to that apps scopes, you generated it with, not to the organisation.